# How do I download Stack Overflow's data?

Tags: support, data-dump

I heard that Stack Overflow's Question/Answer data is downloadable.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data dump used to be hosted on Clearbits, which was shut down at some point.

Stack Exchange is now hosting the data dump  in the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

For more details, you can read the [official blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/).

Comment: Apparently clearbits.net is down, see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213670). This location should work: https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

Comment: Right, but you can find it currently here: [http://blog.stackoverflow.com/tags/cc-wiki-dump/](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/tags/cc-wiki-dump/)