# Is there a problem with the ClearBits data dump?

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-dump

I tried to connect to http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump and got an error message:

> ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE.

Is this a known problem? Do you expect that the problem will be solved soon?

Comment: [Yes](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/clearbits.net), and it's hard to say, that's an issue on their end.

Comment: It also appears as "inactive" [here](http://who.is/whois/clearbits.net) in the Whois Lookup.

Comment: Even clear bits can be cloudy at times, I suppose.

Comment: In the meantime, you can use http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199303/178179 (September 2013 dump)

Comment: Magnet link for the Sept 2013 dump: `magnet:?xt=urn:btih:C472A68F39CD333816098E53AE353E8D90C3E9D3&dn=Stack%20Exchange%20Data%20Dump%20-%20Sept%202013`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have attempted to contact the owner of clearbits.net to find out what the deal is with our hosting.  As far as we were aware he wasn't going anywhere - but plans might have changed.  I'm calling this a temporary outage until we know more.

**Update, Jan 5<sup>th</sup> 2014**: As of right now it appears clearbits will not be coming back online. We are in contact with the previous owner and working on a migration plan to move our data dumps out to https://archive.org/ - we will have an updated blog and meta post when this transition is complete

**Update, Jan 23<sup>rd</sup> 2014**:  We have secured hosting at archive.org for our data dumps.  A post will be coming soon on the details.  For now you can find the new data dump here:

https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

Sorry for the delay - having ClearBits disappear came as a bit of a surprise to us.

Comment: Seems to be down right now @Geoff Dalgas

Comment: Yep, we are aware of the outage.  As of right now it appears clearbits will not be coming back online.  We are in contact with the previous owner and working on a migration plan to move our data dumps out to archive.org - we will have an updated blog and meta post when this transition is complete.

Comment: Awesome. This will help a lot of talented people who don't have or can't afford the luxury of reliable, high bandwidth connections, to cross the digital divide, thank you Geoff!

Comment: Thanks Geoff. Will older data dumps be available too? It would be nice to be able to access all the data dumps that were released.

Comment: Dear Geoff, I am interested in exploring the possibility to host SE data dumps at my institution (one of the Australian Universities): can we get in touch directly? Thanks

Comment: @guido sure - gdalgas@stackoverflow.com

Comment: Dammit! I read you're down for good. I would've wanted to get my hands on the music torrents because I wish I'd had downloaded them.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Are the oldest data dumps that were hosted on ClearBits gone forever, now?