# How many hats did each site get?

Tags: support, statistics, winter-bash-2013

Now that Winter Bash 2013 is over, I would love to know things like "how many of hat XYZ where awarded to people at ABC.SE?"

This information can help us (the communities at the various sites) gauge how active the site is, on a whole, in various things (closing questions, reopening questions, participating in the queues, etc.).

Is there any chance that this summary data will be released?

Answer (score 5):

For a limited time, the [Winter Bash leaderboards](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) are still live. (Hover over the abbreviated numbers to see the actual figures for "hats earned on a site".)

That's all we've got for now. We don't currently have plans to release more hat data, but *if* there is a way to publish it relatively easily we *may* consider it.

**UPDATE**: I looked into this, and it's unlikely to happen. The service we used to host the torrents for our regular data dumps shut down entirely without warning, and we don't have another torrent hosting system set up. Our priority is to get something back in gear for the standard data dump, but that will take a significant amount of time. Only then would we be able to think about releasing Winter Bash data, and by then way fewer people will be caring about it.

Maybe next year.

Comment: "shut down entirely"? I still couldn't find any solid reference, if you have such can you please update [this report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213670/152859)?

Comment: What I'd really like to see is just a simple csv - sites by hats with values of hat counts on that site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Geoff [left a comment yesterday on his answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213670/is-there-a-problem-with-the-clearbits-data-dump#comment693640_213990) over there...we don't have any more information than that.

Comment: @Laura yep, going to embed this into the answer then. Comments are... temporary.

Comment: The issue with the data dump storage has been resolved, since they are now hosted at https://archive.org/details/stackexchange So, perhaps Bash data can go there too, maybe as a separate file (it's not *that* big)?

Answer (score 5):

> 76,588 users from around the network have earned a total of **214,187 hats**!

Here is a screenshot of the top of the site leaderboard:

[image: top of the site leaderboard]

---

Here is the entire leaderboard:

[image: entire site leaderboard]

---

And for good measure, the top of the network-wide leaderboard:

[image: network-wide leaderboard]