# Collect hat stats please

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

Last year I was curious about some hat stats ([How many hats did each site get?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214876/213963)).  Unfortunately, this data wasn't collectable at the time I asked.  Please consider collecting the data *this* year.  You could have an interesting blog post about the data analysis.   Things like:

- Out of all the people who earned hats on the site, what percentage of users on Android.SE earned the different mobile app hats (and similarly for the Apple.SE)
- What is the ratio of "Crabby" people to "Red Shirt" (and "I Voted Today")?
- What was the long term effect of the Resolution hat? (How many comments were deleted? Did this cause any questions to become eligible for roomba deletion having fallen below the "keep because enough comments"?)
- What rooms had the most Sumo Judge hat recipients?

You know, that sort of thing.  There's a lot of data analysis possible to pull out of the hats and it would be really nice to either save and distribute this data or do it yourself (it could be fun).

Comment: Fancy graphs would be interesting, too. Or maybe even a data dump. +1

Comment: ... and how many MSE users get "Business in the front, Party in the back" compared to other sites? (Thanks for the hat!)

Comment: +1. This is technically for 2014 but people have been posting for 2015 ideas [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213574/276098). Keep an eye out for a 2015 post, perhaps this idea will be more visible there.

Answer (score 27):

We are definitely keeping stats this year. The [wrap-up post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/) includes some high-level stats. I'm also planning on publishing at least some of the queries on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) so that people can generate their own statistics. (Note that the results from the public data will be different than   the statistics of hats awarded because of deleted posts and so on.)

## Counts

Here are the raw stats across the network:

| Hat name | Earned | Users | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chameleon | 70,361 | 39,499 | Change your avatar* |
| Fascinating | 34,026 | 25,017 | Upvote accepted and +5 answer |
| Saint Lucia | 25,444 | 19,390 | Vote on 12/15 |
| Werewolf Hunter | 18,977 | 16,879 | Earn a silver badge |
| Warm Welcome | 14,430 | 9,597 | Upvote a first post |
| Fascinating, Ma'am | 12,342 | 10,526 | Upvote famous and +25 question |
| Business in the front, Party in the back | 12,091 | 11,146 | Get up and down voted in a day |
| Solstice | 7,581 | 6,858 | Post or comment on 12/21 |
| Bugdroid | 7,115 | 4,776 | Use the Android app |
| Fear & Loathing | 6,317 | 6,001 | Delete your own answer |
| Joga Bonito | 4,366 | 4,040 | 10 reviews |
| Naruto | 4,363 | 4,273 | Accepted answer with no votes |
| Kofia | 4,152 | 4,019 | First post during Kwanzaa |
| Not a cherry | 3,829 | 2,403 | Use the Apple app |
| Treasure Hunter | 3,020 | 2,891 | Earn a gold badge |
| Imitation Crab | 2,552 | 2,284 | Downvote 5 posts in a day |
| Red Shirt | 2,439 | 2,204 | Downvote 5 bad posts |
| Handegg | 2,425 | 2,168 | Answer scored 7+ |
| Major Award | 1,178 | 1,142 | Bounty answer +1 |
| I Voted Today | 987 | 882 | Vote limit and 10+ questions |
| Selfie | 910 | 888 | Answer your own question |
| Gelt | 813 | 757 | Start a bounty during Hanukkah |
| Sumo Judge | 742 | 650 | Give stars to 8 users in chat |
| HairBoat | 699 | 569 | Respond to Abby |
| Tam o' Shanter | 589 | 487 | Get a star on New Years Eve |
| On The Road | 511 | 451 | Ask using a mobile app |
| Time Lord | 404 | 378 | Edit 5 old questions |
| Waffles | 365 | 331 | Down, edit, upvote a question |
| Bill Lumbergh | 325 | 318 | Answer 5 questions on Saturday |
| Resolution | 244 | 222 | Delete 10 last-year comments |
| Got a Tablet for Christmas | 231 | 213 | Post on Christmas with an app |
| Stockings Hung by the Fire | 223 | 196 | Start a bounty on Christmas |
| Breaking Bad | 220 | 210 | VTC, edit, vote to reopen |
| Mistletoe | 207 | 154 | Chat ±5 min. of 0 UTC 2015 |
| 30 Minutes or Less | 177 | 177 | Get 5 answers in 30 minutes |
| Aztec | 169 | 155 | Collect 20 hats |
| Red Baron | 26 | 26 | Answer a -3 question; later +3 |
| Eureka! | 15 | 15 | Guess a secret hat |

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised how close Crab and Red Shirt are. Nice to know that people were downvoting stuff that actually deserved to be downvoted.

Comment: Are there any plans to keep leaderboards live this year? (asking because of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270396/260841) :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ: We don't have any plans to do things differently this year. But I'll put a bug in the balpha's ear. Every year we say we aren't going to change things and every year we get surprise new features.

Comment: And what about this year? @Jon

Comment: @ShadowWizard: We're not collecting anything different than in previous years.

Comment: @Jon yeah, but will you put anything on SEDE?