# Past Winterbash 2014 results?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

Are the results for **Winterbash 2014** still up anywhere? Specifically the network-wide and individual site results? Some of us on travel.SE were trying to remember how many of each were achieved.

(EDIT) the linked dupe question shows the results for **2013** only. I'm specifically after last year's results.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, other than screenshots.

Comment: [How many hats did each site get?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214876/260841) and [Collect hat stats please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245680/260841)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ - those are great, but for 2013 - I'm after 2014 :/

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ it is, but the answer doesn't answer this one - they have the hat count, but I specified "network-wide and individual site results".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Wayback Machine seems to have the Winter Bash 2014 leaderboard archived:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20150509210612/http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard

In particular, the results for Travel.SE can be found [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150101052553/http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/travel.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 13):

No, they were up for almost a year, but we finally took them down on October 29.

Comment: Not...not even a screenshot? :(

Comment: Why not include these in [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @Werner Because adding new DBs to SEDE is a decent amount of work to do and maintain, and for something that almost nobody cares about anymore after WB is over, that not worth it. It's also counterproductive to the idea that WB is a *temporary* thing.

Comment: @balpha: Good point.

Comment: @balpha what about data dump, even a simple XML?