# Will there be any remains from the Winter Bash after January 4th?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

I feel like this question exists for every year (and the answer is no), but will there be any remains from the Winter Bash after January 4th, the description states *no* though, but I am a fairly new (registered) user and I really don't know.

> Stack Exchange invites you to celebrate the end of a great year …with HATS! As you use your site, you'll discover hats and other items hidden behind certain actions. Collect all of them, some of them, or none of them, but be quick – the hats get put back in their boxes on January 4th!

Comment: Last year they kept the leaderboards up for almost an year, until October. Probably will be the same this year

Comment: Does this include the entire subdomain `http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/` or only `http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard`?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, my source is [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270397/152859).

Comment: OK, found similar to the previous years, too, so it is highly assumable that it won't change especially after reading the comment regarding the data bases.