# How is the end date for Winter Bash decided?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

On the [Winter Bash 2018](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) page I read that Winter Bash will end on January 2nd:

> the hats get put back in their boxes on January 2nd!

Earlier years Winter Bash has ended on [January 4th](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270850/263194):

> the hats get put back in their boxes on January 4th!

How is the end date for Winter Bash chosen?

Comment: Yes, on January 2nd **you will no longer be able to wear your hat!** Which makes the *Glasses With A Number On Top* something that only lasts for a maximum of, I think, 18 or so hours. 8-(

Answer (score 5):

Well, generally Winter Bash lasts about three weeks, and starts either on Monday or Wednesday (see the list below, partially compiled by @rene in a now-deleted answer). If it starts as early as this year, it'll end early as well.

I can't imagine it ends before January 1st, so it'll probably shift next year, but ultimately, it's the Stack Exchange team who decides this.

> 2018: Wednesday, December 12, 2018 - Tuesday, January 1, 2019
>   2017: Wednesday, December 13, 2017 - Tuesday, January 2, 2018
>   2016: Monday, December 19, 2016 - Monday, January 9, 2017
>   2015: Monday, December 14, 2015 - Sunday, January 3, 2016
>   2014: Monday, December 15, 2014 - Sunday, January 4, 2015
>   2013: Monday, December 16, 2013 - Friday, January 3, 2014
>   2012: Wednesday, December 19, 2012 - Friday, January 4, 2013
>   2011: (Hat Dash on Gaming.SE) Friday, December 16, 2011 - Friday, January 6, 2012

Comment: See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319473/282094 - I answered in a comment to my answer to a related question, so as not to bump my answer. Rumor has it, it's the 2nd.