# When does Winter Bash take place?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Winter Bash 2018 took place from December 12th through January 1st. Do all Winter Bash competitions take place at this date range? Where can I look it up?

Comment: @Glorfindel Wait, what? It's not what I asked!

Comment: Then it's unclear (to me) what you're actually asking. Do you want dates from previous Winter Bashes?

Comment: @Glorfindel Are all Winter Bashes take place at the same time?

Comment: @Glorfindel basically, that would be it. I think he is just asking for the dates of the past events and if they are always the same.

Comment: Yeah, I already listed the dates [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321014/295232).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can't be a definitive answer for that, since each year the dates where Winter Bash happens are different.

In a [deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317725/152859), @rene gives the history of the dates:

- 2017: Wednesday, December 13, 2017 - Tuesday, January 2, 2018
- 2016: Monday, December 19, 2016 - Monday, January 9, 2017
- 2015: Monday, December 14, 2015 - Sunday, January 3, 2016
- 2014: Monday, December 15, 2014 - Sunday, January 4, 2015
- 2013: Monday, December 16, 2013 - Friday, January 3, 2014
- 2012: Wednesday, December 19, 2012 - Friday, January 4, 2013
- 2011: (Hat Dash on Gaming.se) Friday, December 16, 2011 - Friday, January 6, 2012

Comment: didn't you post this same answer 6 to 8 days ago?

Comment: @rene [I think that was me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321014/295232).

Comment: @Glorfindel noted, it wasn't my imagination then ....

Comment: @Glorfindel yarg... oops. I remembered only rene's answer. Why this is -8 and the other same question is at +8 is really beyond me. Even after all those years in here, MSE is still a total mystery. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Welcome to Meta :)

Comment: @VerNick lol, thanks! :D