# Use data.stackexchange.com to make some statistics about Hats

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

To make some statistics, I want to use https://data.stackexchange.com/ to find, for example:

- Who have the most Hats until now,
- Who have this or that Hat,
- How many Hat used,
- How many one wear Hat,
- etc.

But I can't find in the **Database Schema** something about the **winter-bash**.  Can someone help me to solve this problem?

**N.B**

I'm new in data.stackexchange.com.

Thank you.

Comment: This was [planned for 2014](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245868/295232) but AFAIK never executed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The database schema doesn't include hats.  Also, even if it did, the data is only refeshed once a week, so for something that moves as quickly as hats, you'd almost never have current information.

It would be possible to write queries for some of the conditions that lead to hats, like gold/silver badges awarded within the right date range, hats involving post timing and scores, and some others.  Some hats depend on private information like the votes you cast, though, and that data isn't in the data dumps.

Answer (score 2):

While it sounds good, it was kind of rejected already by SE developers.

balpha gives the reasoning in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270396/past-winterbash-2014-results#comment876129_270397):

> adding new DBs to SEDE is a decent amount of work to do and maintain, and for something that almost nobody cares about anymore after WB is over, that not worth it. It's also counterproductive to the idea that WB is a temporary thing.

Comment: You convinced me :)