# How can one see one's past hats?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

Can future winterbashYYYY.stackexchange.com site/s be modified so that users can see what hats they obtained in a year? (So for example in 2024, a user could see what hats they obtained in 2023.)

Or some other idea?

Comment: Sadly that's just not possible. It was [suggested before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288528/use-data-stackexchange-com-to-make-some-statistics-about-hats) to add stats to SEDE, this way it would be stored for good, but looks like it's not going to ever happen.

Comment: I've been asking for this [for almost a decade](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213580/223467). I don't think this is ever going to happen :-(

Comment: This is defenetly a good idea to have information about past hats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are blogs for the results of each years' Winter Bash. Last year's Winter Bash closing blog post is [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/01/06/the-bash-is-over-but-the-season-lives-a-little-longer/) and you could see the top 5 users in the leaderboard.

[This](https://stackoverflow.blog/tag/winter-bash/) is the archive link to all past Winter Bash blog posts.

If you're not just interested in the top hat collectors from each year, but you would like to see other users too. You could also use the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/) to see the past years' leaderboard, type in each years' Winter Bash leaderboard link in this format `https://winterbash20XX.stackexchange.com/leaderboard`.