# Could we get some detailed hat stats for 2015?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

I am still missing the ideals presented in [Collect hat stats please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245680/213963) and [How many hats did each site get?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214876/213963).  The [Hats off](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/01/winter-bash-2015-hats-off/) blog post doesn't satisfy.

For each site:

- What is the ratio of Thalia to Melpomene? A venn diagram would be nice. Yes, its 10,015 Melpomene and 1556 Thalias. But how does that break down *per site*?
- How may "Do it Yourself" were awarded? How many question and answer combinations *didn't* qualify.
- What is the timeline of Every! Body! Gets! A Hat! - when did each site have this triggered?
- What percent of users who logged in during winter bash with less than 1 year of time on the network got the Researcher hat?
- For questions that triggered a Batman hat, one week later, what is the status for those questions? Score delta? Answers since reopen? Current question state?
- For questions that triggered a Greeter hat, one week later, what is the status for those questions?
- For users who got the Timey Wimey - how many questions in the 'old' range were edited in Winterbash? How many since then?

The hats are fun, but they also hint at what a given community does and its activity when hats *aren't* present. Being able to look at that can give us a better introspection on the various sites we are active in and look at how to emphasize certain behaviors for the new year.

Comment: These are exactly the sorts of questions I'm interested in! And hope to get to this week, if more important stuff doesn't come up. For now, a few of your questions are already answered in the freshly published [Winter Bash 2015 post-mortem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272735/winter-bash-2015-post-mortem).

Answer (score 4):

So... I did not plan well for this. Data about things like which exact post triggered a given hat for a user aren't stored in the regular database, so coming up with these numbers after the fact turns out to be prohibitively difficult. If I had thought ahead better two months ago, I would've realized that I needed to explicitly ask for extra data to be saved (as I did for the Every! Body! Gets! A Hat! hat) but I didn't do so.

I've made a note to include statistics as a more central part of the planning process for next year, but for now I can only apologize and point you to the stats already published in [the post-mortem analysis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272735/winter-bash-2015-post-mortem), which mainly cover your third bullet point and the list of total hats awarded by hat type.