# Stats on unique hats by site—available anywhere?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash, site-stats

I'm wondering what hats each site has earned at any given time. Perhaps to see how close I am to earning [Just Here for the Hat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/just-here-for-the-hat), or perhaps to see whether a site is highly ranked because they worked for it or because they just have a lot of users with a few hats.

Could there be statistics for unique hats by site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We keep track of the number of unique hats awarded (obviously), but we don't have a leaderboard for that. One of the reasons is that the hat is supposed to be a sort of group achievement. If a community is into hat hunting, they will be paying attention to their [own site's leaderboard](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/webapps.stackexchange.com) and work together to claim new hats toward the Just Here for the Hat hat. It's not intended that people will seek out sites to earn an easy hat. Notice that the network leaderboard tracks total unique hats rather than total hats earned. So earning an extra hat (or two) on some site you never frequent isn't buying you anything.

At the end of the event, we traditionally provide a [statistical summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272735/winter-bash-2015-post-mortem) that includes some details on the community-earned hat. In particular, we list [an approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) of the minimum group required to earn the hat. That way you can get an idea of whether the hat was really a group effort or the work of a small cohort of hat enthusiasts.

Comment: With a name like _Just Here for the Hat_, I thought the whole point was to visit sites you wouldn't otherwise, just to get the hat.

Answer (score 1):

We do have the [leaderboards for hats earned per site](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard). Maybe you could start there.

Comment: But… that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for how many different hats were earned on a given site.