# Access to the stack-exchange data dump

Tags: support, data-dump

I would like to access the Stack Exchange data dump.

I am aware the dump is available as torrent download through [ClearBits](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump), however clearbits is currently down (since at least December 2013 - when I first tried): the site returns a error (113) - No route to host.

Are there other repositories for the data dump, or alternative ways to get the torrents/data?

I have noticed a user has uploaded some of the data on Mega (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198915/is-there-a-direct-download-link-with-a-raw-data-dump-of-stack-overflow-not-a-t)), but this is not an up-to-date dump.

Comment: Maybe this can help: [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20131026055141/http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump)

Comment: Hi MistressDavid, thanks for the idea. I should have said that I tried that (actually, using the Way Back Machine). Yet, it doesn't work when you attempt to access the torrent

Comment: Sorry guys! I did research on stack-exchange for a solution to this, and did not find anything...well few minutes after asking the question I finally find this other [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213670/is-there-a-problem-with-the-clearbits-data-dump), which points out exactly the same issue. So I guess we should continue the discussion on that question rather than here.

Comment: Surely someone has a Torrent file laying around.  Doesn't someone seed these things?

Comment: @RobertHarvey rename it `CLEAN WIN8.1 ISO WITH KEYGEN.torrent` and you'll get much better seeding...

Comment: @MattDMo: Yeah, for about 5 minutes.

Comment: had torrent ran for the past 2 weeks with the torrent obtained through the way back machine...apparently no luck in finding people seeding. Anyway, I would refer people to the discussion I [previously linked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213670/is-there-a-problem-with-the-clearbits-data-dump) as it started sooner and already attracted attention by moderators.