# Broken URL for data.stackexchange.com help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

When using data.stackexchange.com I fail to remember if `as [post link]` is the correct alias to get the url for the post. Luckily the site has an [help](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) link. Unfortunately it is now broken.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: YSoD on Stack Overflow? Now I don't feel so bad...

Comment: Beta sites probably broke it... until fixed, you can travel back in time to see it in its full glory: http://web.archive.org/web/20130816134353/http://data.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We removed the custom AssetPackager that handled client-side resources in favour of the WebGrease functionality provided by the `System.Web.Optimization` helpers, and despite having used the help page to test the path rewrite functionality that gained us, somehow that page ended up pointing to the removed code (which of course causes an exception).

[Fixed now](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/22), [and deployed](https://data.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: This also reminds me that the help page needs to be updated since ClearBits is no more, but I guess that can wait until SE has that fixed.

Comment: Do I need to open an new question for getting the help page content updated., just for tracking/status updates?

Comment: @rene Outside of the now-defunct data dump links, is there anything else that needs updating?

Comment: apart from that clearbits link a reference to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer)  seems helpfull.

Comment: @rene Hmm, let me think on that. You can open a feature request for updating the links if you want, but I will make that change either way [once there's an alternate place to link to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213990/150235).

Comment: You have the clearbits link covered by that question and I assume I can do [a push here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Views/Home/Help.cshtml) instead of cluttering meta with trivial update/feature requests.